# Listening for UITableView events inside a View Controller

Tags: xamarin

I created a View Controller using storyboards and dropped a UITableView on top of it.

My issue is that I can not figure out how to listen for row selections in the UITableView.

I know how it works in UITableViewController.  You override RowSelected.  But this is a table INSIDE of a View Controller.

I am new to Xamarin, and this is driving me crazy.  I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use something similar to this solution:

```
    public class TestTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        public delegate void RowSelectedEventHandler(NSIndexPath selectedIndexPath);

        public event RowSelectedEventHandler RowSelectedEvent;

        protected virtual void OnRowSelectedEvent(NSIndexPath selectedindexpath)
        {
            RowSelectedEventHandler handler = RowSelectedEvent;
            if (handler != null) handler(selectedindexpath);
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            OnRowSelectedEvent(indexPath);
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

So you can do this in your UIViewController:

```
    TestTableViewSource source = new TestTableViewSource();
    source.RowSelectedEvent += RowSelected;
    YourTableView.Source = source;

    private void RowSelected(NSIndexPath path)
    {
        // handle the selected row.
    }
```

Of course this solution can be further improved by extracting RowSelected to an abstract class so you can reuse it later - but that's up to you :).

Comment: I implemented your code with mine, and your answer appears to be what I was looking for.  However, I'm not clear on what I should be putting in GetCell and RowsInSection.  I feel silly for not figuring this out, but can you tell me what I need to have in there?

Comment: @CorporalCuddler you should check out this great article about that:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/

Comment: Roosevelt,  your original code sample, plus your link to the table tutorial, plus some minor tweaking solved my issue.  Thank you!!!